# strg datatime to time delta

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

How to convert string datatime in to timedelta

string = "%y -%m -%d 00:15:00"

date_string = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),string)

date_final = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(date_string)

typeerror = tuple or struct_time argument requried

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: expected output : Timestap('2022-02-04 00:15:00)  ---------------time already defined in string so no changes in time

Comment: @MrFuppes The question is not tagged with Pandas, and OP uses no pandas function here. It seems to be a Python question...

Comment: You should read the doc for `time.mktime`. It does not expect a string. Hence the error. And a timedelta is a difference between two datetime objects. What are you actually trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.combine`:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

out = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.strptime('00:15', '%H:%M').time())
print(out)

# Output
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 4, 0, 15)
```